# why my back button is not triggered in the navigation bar stack show segue?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

[image]

I have 3 VC in here. from the blue one, the user can go either to green or the red one based on some logic.

if the user go from blue to red one, the Back button in the red VC can be used. but if the user go from blue to green, the back button in the green VC can't be used, the user can't go back to the blue VC from greenVC, the problem is only in the greenVC

the video / .gif is in here : http://g.recordit.co/yxSiEd6ji7.gif

the trigger in the blueVC is this code

```
if needSpeaker {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToStep5", sender: nil)
        } else {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToStep6", sender: nil)
        }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        if segue.identifier == "goToStep5" {
            let createEventStep5VC = segue.destination as! CreateEventStep5VC
            createEventStep5VC.newEvent = newEvent
        } else if segue.identifier == "goToStep6" {
            let createEventStep6VC = segue.destination as! CreateEventStep6VC
            createEventStep6VC.newEvent = newEvent
        }
    }
```

and here is the code in the greenVC :

```
import UIKit

class CreateEventStep5VC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var speakerNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var speakerNameTextField: UITextField!

    var newEvent : [String:Any]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("step 5")
        print(newEvent)

        // initial value
        speakerNameLabel.text = ""

        // to make the cursor directly to the textfield when the user open the VC
        speakerNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

        setQuestionTitle()

    }

    @IBAction func nextStepButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let speakerName = speakerNameLabel.text, !speakerName.isEmpty, speakerName != " " else {
            showAlert(alertTitle: "Mohon Maaf", alertMessage: "Anda harus mengisi nama pematerinya terlebih dahulu.", actionTitle: "Kembali")
            return
        }

        newEvent["speaker"] = speakerName
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToStep6", sender: nil)


    }

    // to remove keyboard / cursor if we touch other area
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(false)
    }

}


extension CreateEventStep5VC {

    func setQuestionTitle() {
        let eventTypes = newEvent["eventType"] as! [EventType]

        if eventTypes.contains(.ceramah) {
            questionTitleLabel.text = "Siapa Nama Penceramahnya?"
        }
    }

}


extension CreateEventStep5VC {
    // MARK : Navigation

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToStep6" {
            let createEventStep6VC = segue.destination as! CreateEventStep6VC
            createEventStep6VC.newEvent = newEvent
            navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        }
    }

}


extension CreateEventStep5VC : UITextFieldDelegate {

    // to make live update to UILabel
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let text = textField.text ?? ""
        speakerNameLabel.text = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        return true
    }


}
```

what went wrong in here?

Comment: That button doesn't look like a back button, but an empty bar button item, just remove it from your storyboard, It should have the same text as the other 2

Comment: ahh thats the problem, newbie mistake, I copy the VC on storyboard from another VC. thanks

Comment: Something is different for Green one. As you can see the red one is showing title of green as a back button but not the green one. Can you check the side inspector of both the segues. @Alexa289